# git stash pop prints "deleted by us" for file that was never created on master

Tags: git, git-stash

I am relatively new to git (coming from svn).

I perform the following steps which are mainly that I edit a file on a branch, perform a stash and then try to apply the stash to the master (which does not have this file).:

```
user1:~/gittest$ ls
user1:~/gittest$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user1/gittest/.git/

user1:~/gittest$ touch file1
user1:~/gittest$ git add file1
user1:~/gittest$ git commit -m "committing file1"
[master (root-commit) 7c29335] committing file1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1

user1:~/gittest$ git checkout -b br1
Switched to a new branch 'br1'

user1:~/gittest$ touch file2
user1:~/gittest$ git add file2
user1:~/gittest$ git commit -m "committing file2"
[br1 b565401] committing file2
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file2

user1:~/gittest$ echo "updated.." >> file2
user1:~/gittest$ git add file2 
user1:~/gittest$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on br1: b565401 committing file2
HEAD is now at b565401 committing file2

user1:~/gittest$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

user1:~/gittest$ git stash pop
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file2 deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of file2 left in tree.

user1:~/gittest$ git status
On branch master
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by us:   file2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

My question is why does git print the message "deleted by us" since file2 was never created on master and thus never deleted.

Is this a misleading message, or am I missing something about the way git works.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a misleading message; it's saying deleted, but it was just never there, it doesn't make a distinction between files that were there before and are now deleted, or files that were never there at all, if you look at it from a 'branch perspective'.

`file2` is actually a known file in your git repository, so in some sense it got deleted when you checked out `master`.

Comment: But is this behavior unavoidable? Would it be impossible to fix it, due to the way merging is performed in git (e.g. it has no way to know whether this file was there or not)?

Comment: I would assume it can be fixed, and maybe it is for more recent version of git, but I'm not familiar with the git source code...